# Can LSTMs have weight dimensions bigger than (num_class,num_classes)?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, lstm

I am working on an LSTM but am confused about the weight dimensions.
[image]

Since the output must be one hot (num_classes,1), is it wrong to say that the weights can only be  of size (num_classes ,num_classes)? If weights have dimensions of (100, num_classes), the final layer ht would have a size of (100,1) rather than (num_classes,1). Am I reading this the wrong way? It seems that because the final layer has elementwise multiplication, it is not possible to do a final dot product to achieve an output vector size of (num_classes,1). How can I increase the number of parameters in my model without adding more layers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s typical to have a layer projecting down to the number of classes if the previous layer is larger.